# use of ng-repeat with ng-class and $index

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

i need different classes to be used for each iteration, following code.

**Edit: the index is within the li**

```
<li class="table-view-cell bg_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="agenda in agendas">
        <span class="cell">
            <a data-href="#/agendas/{{agenda.id}}" ng-click="detail($event, agenda.id)">
                <span class="type">{{agenda.date}}</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
```

also Why do we need ng-class, could I not use simple class here?

Comment: you don´t need ng-class if you are interpolating the string. You can use a normal class attribute

Comment: ok, what's ng-class for, an example please

Comment: how can this work? `<li class="table-view-cell" ng-class="bg_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="agenda in agendas">`

Comment: ng-class is when you want to bind a class on a given condition. for example `ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}"` will add the even or odd classes to the element when those values are true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `ng-class`s with just `class`, and add `track by $index` in your ng-repeat.

Or skip track by. Not sure what you are trying to do but, this should get you going:
http://jsfiddle.net/clto/HB7LU/8072/

Answer (score 0):

what about using css pseudo-class [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).
you can apply different css for each child by their index in your css, instead of just creating lots of different class names for each index.

Comment: any example please for using `.agenda li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.agenda li:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: blue;
}` 1 to 4

Comment: got it working, I liked your answer and I'm using it as it's lateral thinking, however, I accepted the other answer for people who're looking an answer for the same question